# Docker on MacOs Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - getcwd

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, docker

I am trying to set up rails 6 with webpacker on docker and I get a weird error once docker up finishes:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - getcwd
```

Once I ssh in the container I get this:

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
```

This is my DockerFile:

```
ARG RUBY_VERSION
# See explanation below
FROM ruby:$RUBY_VERSION

ARG PG_MAJOR
ARG NODE_MAJOR
ARG BUNDLER_VERSION
ARG YARN_VERSION

# Add PostgreSQL to sources list
RUN curl -sSL https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add - \
  && echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ stretch-pgdg main' $PG_MAJOR > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

# Add NodeJS to sources list
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_MAJOR.x | bash -

# Add Yarn to the sources list
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
  && echo 'deb http://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

# Install dependencies
# We use an external Aptfile for that, stay tuned
COPY ./dockerDev/Aptfile /tmp/Aptfile
RUN apt-get update -qq && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq dist-upgrade && \
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    postgresql-client-$PG_MAJOR \
    nodejs \
    yarn=$YARN_VERSION-1 \
    $(cat /tmp/Aptfile | xargs) && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* && \
    truncate -s 0 /var/log/*log

# Configure bundler and PATH
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 \
  GEM_HOME=/bundle \
  BUNDLE_JOBS=4 \
  BUNDLE_RETRY=3
ENV BUNDLE_PATH $GEM_HOME
ENV BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG=$BUNDLE_PATH \
  BUNDLE_BIN=$BUNDLE_PATH/bin
ENV PATH /app/bin:$BUNDLE_BIN:$PATH

# Upgrade RubyGems and install required Bundler version
RUN gem update --system && \
    gem install bundler:$BUNDLER_VERSION

# Create a directory for the app code
RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
COPY package.json /app/package.json
COPY yarn.lock /app/yarn.lock
COPY . /app

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts. Fixes a Rails-specific issue that prevents the server from restarting when a certain server.pid file pre-exists
# COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
# RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
# ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

This is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  app: &app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args:
        RUBY_VERSION: '2.6.3'
        PG_MAJOR: '10'
        NODE_MAJOR: '11'
        YARN_VERSION: '1.13.0'
        BUNDLER_VERSION: '2.0.2'
    image: treasure-dev:1.0.0
    tmpfs:
      - /tmp

  backend: &backend
    <<: *app
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      # !!!! WARNING !!! For MacOs add this line. It does have a cost though
      # https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/#cached
      # - .:/app:cached
      - rails_cache:/app/tmp/cache
      - bundle:/bundle
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
      - packs:/app/public/packs
      - ./dockerDev/.psqlrc:/root/.psqlrc:ro
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV:-development}
      # - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres@postgres
      - BOOTSNAP_CACHE_DIR=/bundle/bootsnap
      - WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=webpacker
      - WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
      - HISTFILE=/app/log/.bash_history
      - PSQL_HISTFILE=/app/log/.psql_history
      - EDITOR=vi
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      # - redis

  # runner:
  #   <<: *backend
  #   command: /bin/bash
  #   ports:
  #     - '3000:3000'
  #     - '3002:3002'

  rails:
    <<: *backend
    command: ["/bin/bash","-c", "script/start-rails"]
    ports:
      - '3054:3054'

  # sidekiq:
  #   <<: *backend
  #   command: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml

  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.10
    volumes:
      - .psqlrc:/root/.psqlrc:ro
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./log:/root/log:cached
    environment:
      - PSQL_HISTFILE=/root/log/.psql_history
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  # redis:
  #   image: redis:3.2-alpine
  #   volumes:
  #     - redis:/data
  #   ports:
  #     - 6379

  webpacker:
    <<: *backend
    command: ["script/start-webpack-dev-server"]
    ports:
      - '3035:3035'
    volumes:
      - .:/app:cached
      - bundle:/bundle
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
      - packs:/app/public/packs
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV:-development}
      - RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV:-development}
      - WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0

volumes:
  postgres-data:
  # redis:
  bundle:
  node_modules:
  rails_cache:
  packs:
```

This is my start-rails script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Preparing container. This may take a while..."
wait_service ${DATABASE_URL:-db}  5432
wait_service webpacker 3035
bundle check || bundle install
yarn install --frozen-lockfile
bundle exec rake db:create
bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rake db:seed
echo "Done."
bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3054 -b '0.0.0.0'"
```

These are my versions of docker-compose and docker:

```
treasure rails-6-new-postgresql % docker -v
Docker version 19.03.4, build 9013bf5
treasure rails-6-new-postgresql % docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b
treasure rails-6-new-postgresql %
```

I've read a bit on google and it is a docker bug, but I did not find how I can get passed it, my rails server won't start because of it. Any ideas?

Update:
This would be the relevant issue on github:
https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1509

A guy said they do this:

```
@ryfow might be on to something. In my case there was no subdirectory mount, but two different containers based on the same image were mounting a volume from the same host directory at the same path inside the container. We have two different services in the same repository with virtually identical dependencies, so docker-compose.yml just launches the same image twice with different commands and configurations. We now have a workaround in place which just retries in a loop until it works, so we haven't noticed the problem in a while, but I suspect it's still happening.
```

But I need a translation for what he is doing, or a piece of code.

Update2 for David:

Dockerfile stays as is

docker-compose can be reduced to:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  app: &app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args:
        RUBY_VERSION: '2.6.3'
        PG_MAJOR: '10'
        NODE_MAJOR: '11'
        YARN_VERSION: '1.13.0'
        BUNDLER_VERSION: '2.0.2'
    image: treasure-dev:1.0.0
    tmpfs:
      - /tmp

  backend: &backend
    <<: *app
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      # !!!! WARNING !!! For MacOs add this line. It does have a cost though
      # https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/#cached
      # - .:/app:cached
      - rails_cache:/app/tmp/cache
      - bundle:/bundle
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
      - packs:/app/public/packs
      - ./dockerDev/.psqlrc:/root/.psqlrc:ro
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV:-development}
      # - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres@postgres
      - BOOTSNAP_CACHE_DIR=/bundle/bootsnap
      - WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=webpacker
      - WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
      - HISTFILE=/app/log/.bash_history
      - PSQL_HISTFILE=/app/log/.psql_history
      - EDITOR=vi
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      # - redis

  rails:
    <<: *backend
    command: ["/bin/bash","-c", "script/start-rails"]
    ports:
      - '3054:3054'

  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.10
    volumes:
      - .psqlrc:/root/.psqlrc:ro
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./log:/root/log:cached
    environment:
      - PSQL_HISTFILE=/root/log/.psql_history
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

volumes:
  postgres-data:
  bundle:
  node_modules:
  rails_cache:
  packs:
```

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve]?  It seems likely that only one or maybe two of those six containers is actually relevant to this problem, for example.  Separating out the Node and Ruby parts of the Dockerfile into separate containers would help, as would reducing the number of volumes.

Comment: @DavidMaze You are right, for this problem specifically the only containers that need to be started are postgresql and rails one

Answer (score 1):

```
ARG RUBY_VERSION
# See explanation below
FROM ruby:$RUBY_VERSION

ARG PG_MAJOR
ARG NODE_MAJOR
ARG BUNDLER_VERSION
ARG YARN_VERSION

# Add PostgreSQL to sources list
RUN curl -sSL https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add - \
  && echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ stretch-pgdg main' $PG_MAJOR > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

# Add NodeJS to sources list
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_MAJOR.x | bash -

# Add Yarn to the sources list
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
  && echo 'deb http://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

# Install dependencies
# We use an external Aptfile for that, stay tuned
COPY ./dockerDev/Aptfile /tmp/Aptfile
RUN apt-get update -qq && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq dist-upgrade && \
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    postgresql-client-$PG_MAJOR \
    nodejs \
    yarn=$YARN_VERSION-1 \
    $(cat /tmp/Aptfile | xargs) && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* && \
    truncate -s 0 /var/log/*log

# Configure bundler and PATH
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 \
  GEM_HOME=/bundle \
  BUNDLE_JOBS=4 \
  BUNDLE_RETRY=3
ENV BUNDLE_PATH $GEM_HOME
ENV BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG=$BUNDLE_PATH \
  BUNDLE_BIN=$BUNDLE_PATH/bin
ENV PATH /app/bin:$BUNDLE_BIN:$PATH

# Upgrade RubyGems and install required Bundler version
RUN gem update --system && \
    gem install bundler:$BUNDLER_VERSION

# Create a directory for the app code
RUN mkdir -p /app

ENV APP_PATH=/app
WORKDIR $APP_PATH
ONBUILD COPY Gemfile* /app/
ONBUILD COPY package.json /app/
ONBUILD COPY yarn.lock /app/
ONBUILD COPY . /app

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts. Fixes a Rails-specific issue that prevents the server from restarting when a certain server.pid file pre-exists
# COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
# RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
# ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

Ok it seems that the answer was to use the ONBUILD command, this seems to have fixed it along with that APP_PATH variable..... I've remade the container 5 times, no more error.

I can't explain why, maybe someone with more knowledge can, but this is the answer, at least for me